# QPushButton - подсветка при наведении - не работает в винде

Tags: c++, qt5

Для **QPushButton** задаю иконку с 3мя установленными картинками: **Normal**, **Disabled**, **Active**.
После сборки и запуска на linux, всё отрабатывает как ожидается - при наведении курсора мыши картинка меняется с **Normal** на **Active**.
А вот в винде - никак не изменяется.

Похоже на какой-то баг. Может кто знает способы обхода?

Код создания кнопки следующий:

```
QIcon ic(":/4Mouse/icons/MousePictures/OnCell.png");
ic.addPixmap(
  QPixmap(":/4Mouse/icons/MousePictures/OnPict.png"), QIcon::Active);
ic.addPixmap(
  QPixmap(":/4Mouse/icons/MousePictures/OnCellGray.png"),QIcon::Disabled);
QPushButton* info = new QPushButton(ic, "", this);
const QSize sz = ic.availableSizes()[0];
info->setIconSize(sz);
info->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
info->setFlat(true);
info->setGeometry(x, 1, sz.width(), sz.height());
info->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor));
```

П. С. Сейчас Qt5.6.3 на винде - последняя поддерживающая ХР.

Comment: Прикладывайте код обработчика смены ваших иконок.

Comment: Никакого обработчика не писал - в linux всё само подсвечивается.

Comment: тогда то, как устанавливаете

Comment: Метод `addPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap, Mode mode = Normal, State state = Off)` имеет третий параметр `State`. Может в нём дело? Вот тут есть [пример](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qtwidgets-widgets-icons-example.html).

Comment: В тексте, сгенирённой для формы, где у меня используются такие же кнопки, устанавливаются все 6 вариантов явно. т.е. и для QIcon::Off и для QIcon::On. Поведение точно такое же.